# Facebooker params empty

Tags: ruby-on-rails, authlogic, facebooker

I am trying to connect facebooker and authlogic using this http://github.com/kalasjocke/authlogic_facebook_connect

I was having problems so began to debug the facebooker gem code. I realized that no params are getting set using the facebook login that have anything to do with facebook. I can push the facebook login button, it brings up the facebook window as it should and I accept/sign into facebook. Then in facebooker/rails/controller.secure_with_facebook_params! I print out params, this is what shows:

```
authenticity_token<pulled out token number>actioncreatecontrollerperson_sessions
```

person_sessions is the name of my user_sessions. Not sure if this makes a difference though...

This is it. Clearly there should be other parameters here. I checked to make sure that my application numbers are all OK with facebooker.yml (although honestly I don't understand why that would matter as I'm not yet making a facebook app, just want to use connect).

Any ideas?? I would be SOOOO thankful if someone could help me out... any clues would be useful!

K

Comment: there is a token after authenticity_token in the params but I left it out.

Answer (score 0):

Argh I think I finally figured it out! Since I don't have an app yet then set_asset_host_to_callback_url in facebooker.yml should be set to false. However, after this is done, you have to close browser as it seems to store previous session. Now to fix my next problem!

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, my problem was that I had set a Site Domain on my application settings page on Facebook itself... I wasted lots of time fiddling with my code and my settings in my rails app when it was a facebook setting all along. Big up to Alex Neth on the authlogic google group in the end. So what I had was

- Application ID 150132505999999
- Application Secret e7fb8001d80e99999999999999999999
- Site URL http:// localhost:3000
- Site Domain         localhost

and what I should have had was

- Application ID 150132505999999
- Application Secret e7fb8001d80e99999999999999999999
- Site URL http:// localhost:3000
- Site Domain

duh, probably an obvious one but I hope this helps someone out somewhere.
(I've had to break up the site url there for spam issues on this site)